# Where is the Â (C2) coming from

Tags: java, jsp, url

For some reason a piece of code replaces spaces with `\u00A0` - i.e. a [Non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). This code is then used to *sanitize* a URL (yes I know that is very bad - in many ways). Strangely, when these are displayed in my test jsp a rogue `Â` appears - why?

Sample JSP to demonstrate the issue.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <%
      String[] parameters = request.getParameterValues("p");
      if (parameters == null || parameters.length == 0) {
        parameters = new String[]{""};
      }
    %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <a href='index.jsp?p=<%="Hello\u00A0there"%>'>A Link</a>
    <p><%=parameters[0]%></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why is the parameter showing as `HelloÂ there`? Where is the `c2` coming from?

**Added**

BTW: The hex of the `parameter` is `48 65 6c 6c 6f c2 a0 74 68 65 72 65` showing the `c2` in-situ.

Comment: I got those when copying stuff from Gmail into a plaintext file. I forgot again and again that you just cannot do that, gmail messes up your plaintext copies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rogue Â appearing is most often an indication that something got encoded using UTF-8, and then decoded back again using a "traditional" code-page character set, e.g. ISO-8859-1, or CP850, or ...

Comment: So in my case what alternative of `getParameterValues` should I use?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, tell your container to properly decode from bytes to characters. In Tomcat, use the `URIEncoding` parameter in your `server.xml`.

Comment: That's it!! Adding `<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>` to my `glassfish-web.xml` file fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

To answer the actual question "*Where is Â (C2) coming from?*", you may find [this article helpful](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm)
Non-breaking space, `0x00A0` in **UTF-16**, is encoded as `0xC2A0` in **UTF-8**.

This [table](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/utf8.htm) may help as well

> **Examples of encoded Unicode characters (in hexadecimal notation)**
>
> ```
> 16-bit Unicode    UTF-8 Sequence
> 0001              01
> 007F              7F
> 0080              C2 80   <-- this was the case of nbsp
> 07FF              DF BF
> 0800              E0 A0 80
> FFFF              EF BF BF
> 010000            F0 90 80 80
> 10FFFF            F4 8F BF BF
> ```