# The code during pasting is adding (Â-c2) breaking whole page

Tags: html, css, utf-8

PROBLEM: charset utf-8 is broken? Even if the code is correct? Please check attached picturespicture, I can't paste it here, so you have to use a link. The first image how it look graphically and for a second I used XVI32 and show you hex difference. Why it happens and how can I prevent it? I think that checking it with XVI32 shows if I am serious.

https://pasteboard.co/JWgM1iz.png
https://pasteboard.co/JWlUcIc.png

PROBLEM: charset utf-8 is broken? Even if the code is correct?
Please check attached picture, I can't paste it here, so you have to use a link.
https://pasteboard.co/JWgM1iz.png

- UTF-8 charset loads in the old file.
- The "dirtiness" of the code and spaces are irrelevant in this case because before it worked, even if I add a code like on the beauty contest, the effects are the same. I left this on purpose, so you can see it worked before. After the file "crash" it is irrelevant what I will do - the effect remains the same - at least partially CSS is not loading. Sometimes a weird characters appear- a proof of another charset in the use.
- I am aware of a fact that if a char set will switch to another than utf-8, the space can become a non-breaking space and break the whole page. It could happen but it is still not a cause. If I remove all spaces and problem already occured- it won't help it.
- In notepad++ utf-8 is visible at the bottom of the screen for both files. In one old file -it works. Results above the code. In the new file - it doesn't. The code is copied from one file to another.
- If in the old file I will cut the content, paste it to excel (I was generating files in excel)and paste back - it stops working.
- If the old file I will copy as a whole in a folder - the code works.
- I was testing it in opera and chrome, firefox. Old file works, file with a pasted code - doesn't.
- I kept the only minimum of the code because was irrelevant. If for example in the working file I will cut everything below a line title and paste back- it still works. If I cut back everything with a charset - it stops to work - forever. No jokes.
- If I copy a working code to excel and paste back to empty html file - it won't work.
- Visual studio code, notepad++ the same results.

I spend on trying to solve this like easily 10-12h. My hands are tied until I will understand what is the cause. I don't even believe what is happening. I am losing my mind. Even Slaanesh can't help me, maybe you can.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                 
<head>                                              
<meta charset="UTF-8">                                              
<title> ygh</title>                             
                                
<style>                         
.huge{
background:black;
color:antiquewhite;
}                               
</style>                                        
                                
<body>                              
                            
                                
                                
    <div class="huge">                  
        <span id="A" >  łłłłłłhello mrf sio. </span>
        <span id="B" >  ssdsdsdsd.  </span>
        <span id="C" >  asasas?     </span> 
    </body>                                  
                                    
                                    
    </html>
```

Comment: Paste text, not pictures of text. Images of text can't read for accessibility, search, or copied as text.

Comment: If I ctr+c from excel and ctrl+p into a html - the problems occurs, which haven't occured before. If I ctrl+c from excel then ctrl+p into a browser address and ctrl+c from there, ctrl+p into a html - yes it works. With a whole code in one line. BTW, the browser address is the most useful "purificator" I ever encountered.  Alright, so the problem occurs when I copy from anywhere and paste code into a html, changing it into "image of text" but when I copy this through a browser "the pure text" is possible. Still, a whole code in one line? Sounds like fun. I don't know what causes it.

Comment: Alright I solved it, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone will have a similar problem, I recommend to use XVI32 to check code. In my case non-visible character was added during encoding. Detailed answer is there.

http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm#download
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622956/where-is-the-Â-c2-coming-from/35623271](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622956/where-is-the-%C3%82-c2-coming-from/35623271)

Also regarding pasting into excel without breaking code, this would be useful https://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-excel

Also regarding what was wrong with these files - they were corrupted with additonal signs (Â-c2) not visible for an eye and basically I left these files. Now every part of code I paste html>notepad/word keep text only>excel and then it works like before.

Answer (score 1):

`charset` is not a valid attribute of `<style>` element. `<style>` inherits charset of html document (in your case defined by `<meta charset=UTF-8>`).
Also `UTF-8` in `<meta charset=UTF-8>` should be set in quotation marks (like `<meta charset="utf-8">`).

Comment: thanks, but it is not the cause of the problem. It is irrelevant. It was like this in the first place and it doesn't change anything. See the screen, still after "style" everything is in yellow. Like I said, it is a weird situation.   https://pasteboard.co/JWdHeDp.png

Comment: @SlaaneshCultist that's weird, I did copy the code 1 to 1 and it didn't show this error - this may be a problem with your CSS interpreter in Visual Studio. Try installing another one (in extensions) and check if it solves tthe problem.

Comment: @SlaaneshCultist also, there are lots of unnecesary whitespace characters in `<style>` - interpreter may go mad due to them

Comment: yes, I told you brother. It is weird. I tried with several interpreters. If I would send you this file but not a code, I am pretty sure if won't work in your machine but a copied code, will work. I am planning to open the last working code and adding letter by letter until the code will be broken. I actually want to known an aswer why it happens. what happens I think I know - it breaks on one of the white spaces which should be interpreted as a clean road, but it is as a road block. Because the paradigm - the charset is changed. If I would find a reply I will notify in this topic.

Comment: Alright, this code works but my real problems remains I will remove every non necessary space even if before it was ignored and see how it goes. So it is really a space somewhere in a really long code. I will flag this as solved for now. Thanks.

Comment: If the problems occurs due to whitespaces, you can try installing another css extension in visual studio code

Comment: These were white spaces but generated behind the screen during copying and pasting. Below I replied what happened and how to solve it, thank you that you tried. I am so relaxed right now you can't imagine.